# how to create a directory/folder in app with current date as a name

Tags: iphone, date, directory

i want to create a folder in our app local directories ...

the file structure i want to create will look like
current date year/month/date the root directory of this structure is year inside that current month inside that current date folders ..

this way i hav to create the folders...

any help appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a straight forward task.
First you have to split the date into components.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSUInteger dateFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:dateFlags fromDate:date];
NSInteger year = [components year];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger day = [components day];
```

Then create the path you want to create.

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *dir = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d/%d", year, month, day];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:dir];
```

and finally, create the directory

```
NSError *error;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:0 error:&error])
    NSLog(@"Error creating path %@ [%@]", path, error);
```

Comment: i want to print also the particular weekday for that date....like sunday or monday...

Comment: you can get the weekday out of NSDateComponents too. add the corresponding constant to dateFlags, I think it's NSWeekDayCalendarUnit. but not sure, I'm on my ipad now,far away from the mac. and if this is in your flags use [components weekDay] to get the number. then use a switch statement or an array to get a weekday string from the weekdaynumber. Just have a look at NSDateComponents documentation to see the real values, it's a good read anyway.

Comment: thanks for that reply,and i want to add my string to file and save it as  name.html and then add this file to created path